# Python nfc module

Tags: python, python-3.x, nfc

I have ACR122U (nfc reader/writer) and I wanted to write a code, which will scan tags and save them. So I started to google about all that kinda stuff like pynfc but its literally not working. I tried this code from [here](http://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import nfc
import ndef
from threading import Thread

def beam(llc):
    snep_client = nfc.snep.SnepClient(llc)
    snep_client.put_records([ndef.UriRecord('http://nfcpy.org')])

def connected(llc):
    Thread(target=beam, args=(llc,)).start()
    return True

with nfc.ContactlessFrontend('usb') as clf:
    clf.connect(llcp={'on-connect': connected})
```

And the error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\forentfraps\Desktop\site.py", line 1, in 
>       import nfc
>
> File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nfc__init__.py", line 22, in 
>       from . import clf                                                  # noqa: F401
>
> File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nfc\clf__init__.py", line 25, in 
>       from . import device
>
> File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nfc\clf\device.py", line 32, in 
>       from . import transport
>
> File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nfc\clf\transport.py", line 28, in 
>       import termios
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios'

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Apparently termios is still not supported in Windows. https://github.com/xolox/python-capturer/issues/4

Comment: It seems that you are using python 3.x, nfcpy only supports python2.x

Comment: Apparently, it does support python 3.x, as the document here indicates: https://readthedocs.org/projects/nfcpy/downloads/pdf/latest/